# UIAlertController Does Not Return User Input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm using `UIAlertController` for the first time.  I need to prompt the user for an input.  Anyway, the following is what I have.

```
- (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Type something.") preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *noButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];
    UIAlertAction *yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Enter") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //NSString *input = alert.textFields[0].text;
        //NSLog(@"input was '%@'", input);
        UITextField *textField = alert.textFields[0];
        NSLog(@"%@",textField.text); // <====== It's not returned

    }];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(alertTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [yesButton setEnabled:NO];
    }];
    [alert addAction:noButton];
    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)alertTextFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = (UIAlertController *)self.presentedViewController;
    if (alertController) {
        UITextField *textfield = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
        UIAlertAction *okAction = alertController.actions.lastObject;
        okAction.enabled = [self validateName2:textfield.text:5]; // function for validating user input
    }
}
```

For some reason, when the user tap Yes, the application doesn't return user input.  In fact, Xcode dashes 'text' as in '`NSString` *input = alert.textFields[0].text.  A strange thing is that `UIAlertView` doesn't return user input.  That's why I've switched to `UIAlertController`.

[image]

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([alertView tag] == 101) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSString *username = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
            NSLog(@"%@",username); // <====== It's never returned.
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, I wonder what I'm doing wrong with `UIAlertController`?

Muchos thankos

p.s.  I'm using Xcode 6.4 (6E35b).  This issue may be caused by Xcode.  If I debug the code with the iPad2 simulator, it'll actually return user input while it doesn't if I use the iPhone4S simulator.

Comment: You aren't using a `UIAlertView`. You are using a `UIAlertController`. You can't use `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods with a `UIAlertController`. Two completely different classes.

Comment: I copied your alert controller related code and working fine, but as @rmaddy said, alert controller and alert view are different classes, don't mess these together

Comment: No, I am not using UIAlertView.  I stated that the second set of code didn't work when I used UIAlertview.  That's why I've switched to UIAlertController.  I'm sorry for not fully explaining my situation.

Comment: can you please try `NSLog(@"%@",[alert.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text);`

Comment: @Syed Ali Salman I cannot do that as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @ElTomato I have done same many times.

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: @Syed Ali Salman It says Property 'text' not found on object of type 'id.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101151/discussion-between-syed-ali-salman-and-el-tomato).

Answer (score 2):

Use this for textField in alertcontroller

```
__block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
UIAlertController *alertController;

alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                     message:message
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.tag = 1001;
     textField.delegate = weakSelf;
     textField.placeholder = @"";

     [textField addTarget:weakSelf action:@selector(alertTextFieldDidChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
 }];


//OK Button
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               UITextField *textField = alertController.textFields.firstObject;

                               // Do stuff here
                           }];



[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void)alertTextFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
 {
   alertController = (UIAlertController *)self.presentedViewController;
   if (alertController)
   {
     UITextField *textField = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
     UIAlertAction *okAction = alertController.actions.lastObject;

     okAction.enabled = textField.text.length > 0; // condition to enable button
   }
}

 #pragma mark - UITextField delegate methods

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `UITextFieldDelegate` to handle the textField!

Set `textField.delegate = self` and then use the `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` method to do what you do in `alertTextFieldDidChange` if the `replacementString` has a length of > 0.

You are provided with delegate methods for UITextField so you don't have to create the selectors yourself, I recommend you use them to their fullest!

Here are the docs in case you want to know more! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: I don't see why this question has anything to do with UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: You would need to use UITextFieldDelegate to handle when the text is being changed with a UITextField. You try to use `[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(alertTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];` however, if you check out the docs on `UIControlEventEditingChanged`, it says 
    `UIControlEventEditingChanged`
    `A touch making an editing change in a UITextField object.` So changing text will not be handled with the method you are currently using!

Comment: Also here is the [docs link to UIControlEventEditingChanged](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events))

Comment: How does that have to do with alert.textFields[0] being not recognized by Xcode?